# How can I iterate twice in a table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with two fields: id1, id2 and I need to calculate the value of a new field (newField) based on these. The keys are used like a params in another sql that retrieve the value of the new field.

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE id1 INT;
  DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR FOR SELECT id1 FROM Table1;
  DECLARE id2 INT;
  DECLARE cursor2 CURSOR FOR SELECT id2 FROM Table1;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

 OPEN cursor1;
 read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cursor1 INTO id1;
    IF done THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;

    OPEN cursor2;
    read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cursor2 INTO id2;
    IF done THEN
       LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;

    UPDATE Table1 SET newField = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table2 WHERE id1 = id1 AND id2 = id2 

END LOOP;
CLOSE cursor2;

  END LOOP;
  CLOSE cursor1;
END
```

For example:

**Table1**

```
id1 id2 newField 
1    1    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table2 WHERE id1 = 1 AND id1 = 1
1    2    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table2 WHERE id1 = 1 AND id1 = 2
1    3    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table2 WHERE id1 = 1 AND id1 = 3
1    4    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table2 WHERE id1 = 1 AND id1 = 4
2    1    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table2 WHERE id1 = 2 AND id1 = 1
2    2    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table2 WHERE id1 = 2 AND id1 = 2
2    3    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table2 WHERE id1 = 2 AND id1 = 3
2    4    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table2 WHERE id1 = 2 AND id1 = 4
```

I would like to obtain a procedure or similar that allows to iterate throught the table and fill the newField field.

Regards

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic would all help.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you just want a window function:

```
select id1, id2, count(*) over (partition by id1, id2) as newfield
from t;
```

Window functions are available starting in MySQL 8+.

In earlier versions, you would use `GROUP BY` and `JOIN`:

```
select id1, id2, newfield
from t join
     (select id1, id2, count(*) as newfield
      from t
      group by id1, id2
     ) tt
     using (id1, id2);
```